# is object visible?

Tags: python, visibility

Object.is_visible or Object.hide is not sufficient to tell me if the object is actually visible in the viewport.

Is there a function that will tell me if the object is truly visible or not, taking into account layers and local/global view?

Comment: Can you explain why is_visible is not enough?

Comment: Unless something's changed since I asked the question, is_visible was not sufficient in telling me if the object is visible in different contexts, like if it was outside of local view or the set visible layers. it would remain true, even if these criteria were false.